# Read csv from hdfs with spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I'm using spark 2.3.0 and hadoop 2.9.1
I'm trying to load a CSV file located in hdfs with spark

```
scala> val dataframe = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").schema(schema).load("hdfs://127.0.0.1:50075/filesHDFS/data.csv")
```

But I get the following error:

```
2018-11-14 11:47:58 WARN  FileStreamSink:66 - Error while looking for metadata directory.
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "Desktop-Presario-CQ42-Notebook-PC/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":50070;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 127.0.0.1 use the default FS name. You can find it in the core-site.xml file under the property fs.defaultFS

It should solve your problem.